# What is the difference between an n-node tree and a binary tree?

Tags: java, tree

Can anyone tell me what the differences are between an n-node tree and a binary tree?

Comment: this is too broad kind of question. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and happy learning about trees

Comment: [More information about K-ary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree)

Answer (score 1):

Binary tree nodes have max 2 sub-nodes, n-node trees have max `n` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

i would say they are the same, meaning they are trees:

- binary tree is a 2-node tree => maximum of 2 child per node (decision tree)
- n-node tree => maximum of n child per node

Comment: is there any website that give explanation about n node tree?